# Having header viewable while using .slideToggle

Tags: javascript, slidetoggle, jquery-hover

I have a div (within #slideup there is a div with a div with PHOTOS) that I want "PHOTOS" to be positioned at the bottom, but when you hover over it it expands up and the header then goes to the top of the div. When your cursor then leaves the div, I would like "PHOTOS" to return back to the bottom.

Here is my feeble attempt. I can't seem to offset the header to where it is viewable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/JcBAd/2315/

```
$("#other-guy").hover(function () {
  $("#slideup").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Here is an example (kind of), http://www.barackobama.com/. In the right column, when you hover over "Immigration Reform" and you'll kind of see what I'm looking for. Only difference is I want the header to stick to the top.

Comment: so the content in #other-guy (besides the #slideup) you want this on the bottom of the div? I dont understand it. It's kind off confusing with your question and the naming of your IDs

Comment: I should have been more clear... I would like the "div" with the text of "photos" to always be seen. Like to have it offset so it's seen.

Comment: You are using a hover and you want it always to be seen?
You can replace slideToggle with slideDown and it will slide down once on your hover, and will be always seen that way.

Comment: you dnt want that hover effect right

Comment: First off I want to apologize for my poor wording of this question. I need it to slideup from the bottom, with dark gray box with the header PHOTOS to always be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery .animate() for example. Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JcBAd/2332/).

JS Code here:

```
 $("#other-guy").hover(function () {
        $("#slideup").stop().animate({'bottom' : 0}, 'fast');   /* open */ 
    },

    function(){
        $("#slideup").stop().animate({'bottom' : -180}, 'fast');    /* close */
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Hover effect thats the reason your div is shown only when you place mouse over it
To use your code without that hover effect remove the javascript code and change your HTML to

```
<div id="other-guy">
<div style="background: #333; color: #FFF;">PHOTOS</div>
```

it will work.
and yup **what is hover effect?** just for your interest have a [look](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Comment: No, I want the hover effect. I want PHOTOS to be at the bottom, hover over, then it expands up with PHOTOS at the top with additional information below.

Comment: I added an example in my initial question that sort of has what I'm looking for... maybe that will give you a better visual of what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: @user2282821 for that you can achieve that with jQuery http://www.freshdesignweb.com/jquery-mouseover.html